# PHP Sort a array by specific value

Tags: php, arrays

i want so replace something in a array, but the array isn´t sorted. So maybe you know how i can fix the problem.

I´ve a array with a few of this element.

`<media type="image" id="image5" label="book5.jpg" group="image" source="list2/Schuh2.jpg" url="image5/0.jpg" icon="image5/0.jpg"/>`

How can i sort the array by the value of lable? so that first i get for example from

Lables:

```
 book3
 book4
 book2 

 --> 
 book2
 book3
 book4
```

i hope you know what i mean :D thank you ;-)

Comment: And google didn't give you answer??? First in list with your question "PHP Sort a array by specific value" -> google: http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was, that i can´t sorte bei the one value `['id']` so i has create me one array with all the Informations, and a second only with the `['id']` of the pictures.

Input and load the XML-File.

```
$mashTemplateFile = 'C:\Users\...\test.xml';
$mashTemplate = simplexml_load_file($mashTemplateFile);
$mash = $mashTemplate->mash;
```

declare the arry's

```
$imageArrayMedTemp = array();
$imageArrayMedID = array();
$imageArrayMed = array();
```

put all the information from the media in the array `$imageArrayMedTemp` and only the `['id']`into the array `$imageArrayMedID`.

```
foreach ($mash->media as $med) {
    if ($med['type'] == 'image') {
        array_push($imageArrayMedTemp , $med);
        array_push($imageArrayMedID , $med['id']);
    }
```

now i sort the array with the `['id']`'s

```
natsort($imageArrayMedID);
```

after sorting i will put the information from the array `$imageArrayMedTemp` into a new array `$imageArrayMed`, storing by when the key of both is the same.

```
foreach ($imageArrayMedID as $key1 => $value1) {
    foreach ($imageArrayMedTemp as $key2 => $value2) {
        if($key1 == $key2){
            array_push($imageArrayMed,$value2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming unique book#.jpg images you could do something like ...

```
<?php
$sortedArray = array();
foreach ($unsortedArray as $item ) {
    $sortedArray[explode('.', explode('label="book', $item)[1])[0]] = $item;
}
ksort($sortedArray);
foreach ($sortedArray as $item ) {
    echo $item;
}
?>
```

I did not test this.

UPDATE:
Someone else's suggestion to use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) is a good one. Something like this ...

```
<?php
function compareElements($a, $b) {
    $aNum = explode('.', explode('label="book', $a)[1])[0];
    $aNum = explode('.', explode('label="book', $b)[1])[0];
    return ($aNum < $bNum) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($arrayOfElements, "compareElements");
foreach ($arrayOfElements as $element) {
    echo $element;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$books = array('book3', 'book4', 'book2');
sort($books);

or

$books = array('label1' =>'book5.jpg', 
                   'label2' => 'book4.jpg', 'label3' => 'book3.jpeg');
asort($books);     // sorts by value (ascending)

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hack

```
foreach($a as $k => $media) {
    $parts = explode(' ',$media);
    foreach($parts as $part) {
        $kv = explode('=', $part);
        if ($kv[0] == 'label') {
            $a[$kv[1]] = $media;
            unset($a[$k]);
        }
    }
}

ksort($a);
```

or look at usort() which let you use your own comparison function